# How to divide a column by the number of rows with equal id in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

| Id | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 3 | 100 |

My goal is to divide the price for each observation by the number of rows with the same Id number. The expected output would be:

| Id | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 |

However I am having some issues finding the most optimized way to conduct this operation. I did manage to do this using the code below, but it takes more than 5 minutes to run (as I have roughly 200k observations):

```
# For each row in the dataset, get the number of rows with the same Id and store them in a list
sum_of_each_id=[]
for i in df['Id'].to_numpy():
    sum_of_each_id.append(len(df[df['Id']==i]))

# Creating an auxiliar column in the dataframe, with the number of rows associated to each Id
df['auxiliar']=sum_of_each_id

# Dividing the price by the number of rows with the same Id
df['Price']=df['Price']/df['auxiliar']
```

Could you please let me know what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groupby` with `transform`.

- Make groups on the basis of id using `groupby('Id')`
- Get count of values in a group for each row using `transform('count')
- Divide `df["Price]` by that series which contains count.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[1,1,1,2,2,3],"Price":[300,300,300,400,400,100]})

df["new_Price"] = (df["Price"]/df.groupby("Id")["Price"].transform("count")).astype('int')

print(df)

   Id  Price  new_Price
0   1    300        100
1   1    300        100
2   1    300        100
3   2    400        200
4   2    400        200
5   3    100        100
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "price": [300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 100]})
df.set_index("id") / df.groupby("id").count()
```

Explanation:

- `df.groupby("id").count()` calculates the number of rows with the same Id number. the resulting DataFrame will have an Id as index.
- `df.set_index("id")` will set the Id column as index
- Then we simply divide the frames and pandas will match the numbers by the index.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very clever and simple way to go about it, and it also worked!